# strategy exit in pine

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am having trouble with the final stages of my code.

```
is_below_3sd = close < L3
is_rise_into_3sd = ta.crossover(close, L3)
take_profit_long = ((U3 - U2)*3)
stop_loss_long = (U3 - U15) 
take_profit_short = ((L3 - L2)*3)
stop_loss_short = (L3-L15)
 
if ((cnt > 5) and is_rise_into_3sd)
    bingo := true
 
if (not na(k) and not na(d))
    //code to define if k is in overbought zone and k crossover d of more than 2 and ema is uptrend and enter a long trade
    if (co and k < OverSold and is_uptrend and ((k - d) > 2 ) and ((U15 < close) and (close < U3)) and is_fall_into_3sd)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long") 
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", from_entry ="Long", limit = take_profit_long, stop = stop_loss_long)
    //code to define if k is in oversold zone and k crossunder d is more than 2 and ema in downtrend and enters a short trade
    if (cu and k > OverBought and is_downtrend and  ((d - k) > 2) and ((L15 > close) and (close > L3)) and is_rise_into_3sd)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short") 
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", from_entry ="Short", limit = take_profit_short, stop = stop_loss_short)
```

I am basically using a mixture of emas and stochastic alongside the strategy which longs or shorts when it enters Bollinger bands from either above or below (e.g. U3 - U2 is the difference between 2 bollinger bands). However, the issue I am having is that the strategy.exit function is not working correctly and I really am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Put *strategy.exit* outside of the *if*
something like that:

```
if (not na(k) and not na(d))
    //code to define if k is in overbought zone and k crossover d of more than 2 and ema is uptrend and enter a long trade
    if (co and k < OverSold and is_uptrend and ((k - d) > 2 ) and ((U15 < close) and (close < U3)) and is_fall_into_3sd)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long") 
    //code to define if k is in oversold zone and k crossunder d is more than 2 and ema in downtrend and enters a short trade
    if (cu and k > OverBought and is_downtrend and  ((d - k) > 2) and ((L15 > close) and (close > L3)) and is_rise_into_3sd)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short") 

strategy.exit("Long Exit", from_entry ="Long", limit = take_profit_long, stop = stop_loss_long)
strategy.exit("Short Exit", from_entry ="Short", limit = take_profit_short, stop = stop_loss_short)
```